# AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml - Failure packaging

Tags: azure, build, tfs

I am trying to set up a build using the AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml template as the starting point. My scenario is a very simple one, a single web role, a unit test project, and a second test project that runs after deployment to verify specifications using specflow.

I had all of this working perfectly on sunday night, and the only change since was a check in of code by a colleague - the code he checked in is just built i.e. it doesn't contribute to the build process.

I am having an issue at the point MSBuild is run. The last action that seems to execute before the failure is for the web role :

**Built $/Data Services Layer/Audit/Main/Source/Code/Audit/Audit.csproj for default targets**

This runs for 26 seconds before moving on to the next step (which I can only assume is the way the Azure template packages and deploys a service as I am not using NuGet for anything other than using packages in my project):

**Built $/Data Services Layer/Audit/Main/Source/.nuget/NuGet.targets for target(s) _DownloadNuGet.**

this then results in errors happening in my build as such:

**C:\a\src\Source.nuget\NuGet.targets (97): Unable to find 'C:\a\src\Source\Code\Audit\bin\Audit.dll'. Make sure the project has been built.
 C:\a\src\Source.nuget\NuGet.targets (97): The command ""C:\a\src\Source.nuget\NuGet.exe" pack "C:\a\src\Source\Codh:e\Audit\Audit.csproj" -Properties "Configuration=Debug;Platform=AnyCPU" -NonInteractive -OutputDirectory "C:\a\bin" -symbols" exited with code 1.**

This is actually the second time this problem has occurred - I managed to get it working again after the first time it broke by uploading all my NuGet packages into source rather than using NuGet restore, and recreating the cloud service & related deployment configuration etc again from scratch. I have no idea what part of this fixed the problem but it started building again.

Has anyone got any ideas with this one?

Even though logging is set to the diagnostic setting I am not getting anything more than the above error to go by and I'm a little stumped. It is particularly annoying that this has happened twice so I'd like to know exactly what has caused it as I don't like it when things work and then suddenly stop working - makes me nervous.

Anyway - any help would be greatly appreciated to stop my poor head from hurting any more.

Thanks

Andy

Comment: A bit of a delayed response but in case anyone has similar issues - this turned out to be an issue with the NuGet package restore I had set up. As soon as I jumped through the required hoops to revert back to storing all NuGet DLLs in source my problems went away.